# Limit of $P(100(X_1+\cdots+X_n)>97n)$ as $n \to \infty$ for $(X_k)$ i.i.d.

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be iid random variables with the following distribution: $P(X_1=0)=\frac{1}{18}$,  $P(X_1=1)=\frac{8}{9}$, and  $P(X_1=2)=\frac{1}{18}$.

Let $T_n=100(X_1+\cdots+X_n)$. Determine the limit of $P(T_n>97n)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Attempt:
$P(T_n>97n)=P\left(\frac{T_n-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}>\frac{97n-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\cong\Phi(-0.09\sqrt{n})$ by the CLT. I am not sure whether my application is correct though, and I'm stuck here.

Comment: Try using the weak law of large numbers for a more rigorous approach.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Phi(-0.09\sqrt{n})=\Phi(-\infty)=0$

Comment: @RandowMalk The appeal to CLT to deal with limits of $P(X_1+\cdots+X_n\geqslant xn)$ for some fixed $x$ is wrong. Please reread a rigorous statement of CLT.

Comment: @MANMAID The appeal to CLT to deal with limits of $P(X_1+\cdots+X_n\geqslant xn)$ for some fixed $x$ is wrong. Please reread a rigorous statement of CLT.

Comment: @Did yes, that is wrong! But $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}P\Big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma}\leq x_k\Big)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\Phi(x_k)=\Phi(x)$$ is this wrong?(I want to know...)

Comment: @MANMAID *That one* is correct (and not what is needed here).

Answer (score 1):

Setting $\mu:=\mathbb EX_1$ it is not difficult to find $\mu=1$.

Observe that: $$|\overline{X}_n-1|<0.03\implies\overline{X}_n-1>-0.03$$
and:$$\overline{X}_n-1>-0.03\iff T_n>97n$$

So we have: $$P(T_n>97n)\geq P(|\overline{X}_n-\mu|<0.03)=1-P(|\overline{X}_n-\mu|\geq 0.03)$$
Now apply the [WLLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law).